# Virtual ethernet config file missing in /centos/redhat

Tags: centos, redhat, linux-networking

I am seeing virtual ethernet files like eth0:1 eth0:2 eth0:3 in "ifconfig -a". How do I find the exact config files related to these virtual ethernets? I am not finding any references in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts directory. I am referring to CentOS/Redhat linux. However eth0:1 eth0:2 & eth0:3 are still up. 
I've searched in /etc/networks, /etc/hosts, /etc/sysconfig/network files as well. No luck in finding the config file. I am also searching under /u01/app/12.1.0.2/grid_1/ & /u01/app/12.1.0.2/grid_1/bin. Didn't find any clue.

Comment: Managed by NetworkManager ? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-Installing_NetworkManager#sec-The_NetworkManager_Daemon

Comment: Ya, NetworkManger is running. The "oracle" is  installed and configured (may be rac) and I would like to read the config files of the virtual ethernets.

Comment: If a cluster manager (such as Oracle RAC)  is installed virtual / floating ip-addresses will be created not from "normal" network configuration files, nor by NetworkManager but by that tool.

Comment: Thanks HBrujin. That's what I was thinking. Even if it's not created from normal network config files still we should see the config files from OS standpoint.